Displaying an image 25 times (5x5) in windows forms using 2 for loops, image displays 1x25
Today is the first day of the course Programming 2 (C#) and I need to display a small jpg 25 times in a 5x5 grid using 2 embedded for loops. The first course only covered console apps so this is my first foray into Forms and using external files and this is the first exercise in the book.
I have the program working but the images display in a single row instead of 5 rows of 5. Not entirely sure what is going wrong as the for loops should be correct as far as i can see(?) I know it's going to be something really stupid and obvious!
Here's my code...
namespace Ovning1._3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            int x = 0, y = 0, width = 50, height = 50;
            PictureBox[,] pictures = new PictureBox[5,5];
            for (int r = 0; r < 5; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
                {
                    pictures[r,c] = new PictureBox();
                    pictures[r,c].Left = x;
                    pictures[r,c].Top = y;
                    pictures[r,c].Width = width;
                    pictures[r,c].Height = height;
                    pictures[r,c].BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\iamdu\\Documents\\School\\Programmering 2\\Ovning1.3\\Ovning1.3\\resources\\images\\flower.jpg");
                    pictures[r,c].Click += PbxFlower_Click;

                    this.Controls.Add(pictures[r,c]);
                    x += width;
                }
            }
        }

        private void PbxFlower_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox clickedFlower = (PictureBox)sender;
            clickedFlower.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}

I've stared at the code for the last hour and have no idea what I'm doing wrong. The book has not given any information about how to use Forms and only briefly talks about 2d arrays, which are also new to me and were not covered in the first course.

You are missing a line to go to a new line: x = 0; y += height somewhere after adding a row.

This solved it, Sinatr. Thanks for the help!

The Left and Top area properties of the PictureBox which defines where the image will be displayed.
You put all the images near the same location - (0,0), (0,1), ... ,(1,1), ..., (5,5).
You want position them relatively to image size, so you need assign Left = x * width and Top = y * height.

You miss x += width; line, the images are put in one line. But idea to caclulate and set Location directly for controls of same size is easier indeed.
